# How to use stripe payment in android application

Tags: php, android, stripe-payments

I am following this tutorial.

https://www.sitepoint.com/integrating-stripe-into-your-android-app/

But data are not displayed in Listview.I have confusion with what to put in the charg.php file and require 'vendor/autoload.php'

Please help me.

Answer (score -1):

That tutorial appears to be using a really old version of Stripe's Android SDK; you'll probably want to follow [Stripe's tutorial](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android) and use the newest SDK version available.

Stripe's Android tutorial works alongside the iOS server-side example here: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/tree/master/example

The example is for iOS, but the iOS and Android SDKs both have the same server-side requirements.  It's also in Ruby, but you should be able to extract from that the necessary steps - and 'routes'/scripts needed - to move forward with this.

Comment: I also referred this tutorial but, i do not  understand this tutorial.In this project there are multiple project available from them which one is right project and where is php code

Comment: If possible please give me steps how to do it

Comment: Sorry, I totally gave the wrong server side example link last time.  Try the above - which is still in Ruby, but you should be able to extract the relevant parts that need to be in PHP with a bit of digging/investigation.